# NSOpenPanel - Set file type?

Tags: cocoa

Just looking on what I would use to only allow specific files to be selected (Images for now)

`setFileTypesArray` returns

> NSOpenPanel may not respond to -setFileTypesArray:

and then the panel doesn't open up at all.  Heres my code:

```
    NSArray  * fileTypes = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"png",@"tiff",@"baz",nil];

NSLog(@"Button Pressed");
[textField setStringValue:@"Test"];
int i; // Loop counter.

NSOpenPanel* openDlg = [NSOpenPanel openPanel];

[openDlg setCanChooseFiles:YES];
[openDlg setFileTypesArray:fileTypes];
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You're looking for a delegate method from NSSaveOpenPanel's delegate

```
-(BOOL)panel:(id)sender shouldShowFilename:(NSString *)filename
{
        NSString* ext = [filename pathExtension];
        if (ext == @"" || ext == @"/" || ext == nil || ext == NULL || [ext length] < 1) {
                return TRUE;
        }

        NSLog(@"Ext: '%@'", ext);

        NSEnumerator* tagEnumerator = [[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"png", @"tiff", @"jpg", @"gif", @"jpeg", nil] objectEnumerator];
        NSString* allowedExt;
        while ((allowedExt = [tagEnumerator nextObject]))
        {
                if ([ext caseInsensitiveCompare:allowedExt] == NSOrderedSame)
                {
                        return TRUE;
                }
        }

        return FALSE;
}
```

Then, set your panel's delegate to "self", or wherever your define this method above.

Answer (score 29):

How about `[openDlg setAllowedFileTypes:fileTypes];`?

Comment: This is by far the best method to filter by file types

Comment: This property is deprecated starting with macOS Big Sur, does anyone know of a recommended replacement?

Answer (score 12):

You may wan to check out

```
[panel setAllowedFileTypes:[NSImage imageTypes]];
```

Or implement the delegate NSOpenSavePanelDelegate

and implement

```
- (BOOL)panel:(id)sender shouldEnableURL:(NSURL *)url {

    NSString * fileExtension = [url pathExtension];
    if (([fileExtension  isEqual: @""]) || ([fileExtension  isEqual: @"/"]) || (fileExtension == nil)) {
        return YES;
    }

    NSSet * allowed = [NSSet setWithArray:@[@"png", @"tiff", @"jpg", @"gif", @"jpeg"]];
    return [allowed containsObject:[fileExtension lowercaseString]];

}
```

Comment: Note: In 10.10 `[NSImage imageFileTypes]` was deprecated and the preferred method is now `[NSImage imageTypes]`

Answer (score 8):

The method you're looking for is `setAllowedFileTypes` -- see the docs for the parent class, [NSSavePanel](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSSavePanel_Class/Reference/Reference.html%23//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSSavePanel).

Answer (score 2):

This did work for me :

```
 NSArray  * fileTypes = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"png",@"jpg",@"tiff",nil];

[openDlg setAllowedFileTypes:fileTypes];
```

Answer (score 2):

my two cents for osx / swift 5
(You can specify title, and bring to "pictures" folder.

```
override func showChooseImageDialog(title: String){

    let openPanel = NSOpenPanel()
    openPanel.canChooseFiles = false
    openPanel.allowsMultipleSelection = false
    openPanel.canChooseDirectories = false
    openPanel.canCreateDirectories = false
    openPanel.title = title
    openPanel.allowedFileTypes = NSImage.imageTypes

    openPanel.directoryURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: picturesDir() )

    
    openPanel.beginSheetModal(for:self.view.window!) { (response) in
        if response == .OK {
            let selectedPath = openPanel.url!.path
            
            // do whatever you what with the file path
            
        }
        openPanel.close()
    }
    
}
```